# Como hacer conexión remota mysql mediante php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Como puedo hacer conexión remota a la mysql de otro hosting compartido mediante php.

Comment: Tu pregunta esta mal formulada y no se sujeta a [ask] lo que puede generar su cierre

Comment: Hola @BetaM no pensé que estaría mal hecha mi pregunta, soy nuevo por aquí y voy a cambiar el contexto de mi pregunta.

Comment: Lee la guía sobre como preguntar que te compartí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo agrega el dominio al que deseas conectarte desde los datos de conexión `$ServerName = "HostingZ.com";`, también deberás agregar la ip del servidor de tu página externa desde el Cpanel donde se encuentra la consulta, en MySQL Remoto/añadir anfitrión de acceso.

Consulta más documentación desde [éste artículo](https://www.baulphp.com/conexion-remota-mysql-usando-php-ejemplo-completo/)

Comment: Genial ayudar, pero idealmente esperemos a que el OP mejore su pregunta pues de lo contrario su publicación puede quedar cerrada

Comment: Muchas gracias @Saúl, ahora tocara saber como sacar la dirección IP de mi otro hosting.